# ¿Por qué la condición, hecha en JavaScript, nunca se cumple para el else?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema al imprimir un mensaje en consola, pues imprime correctamente *buena elección*, pero al momento de cambiar el parámetro de respuesta a *No* me sigue imprimiendo *buena elección* cuando en teoría debería imprimir *estas seguro?*.

¿Qué error tengo en el código o qué concepto de JavaScript no estoy aplicando bien?

```js
function imprimirMensaje(respuesta) {

  contestado = respuesta;

  if (contestado = "si") {
    console.log("buena eleccion");
  } else {
    console.log("estas seguro?");
  }
}

imprimirMensaje("si");
```

Comment: Por qué cuando comparas debes usar doble e idealmente triple símbolo de `=` quedando así `if(contestado === "si"){`

Comment: Al momento estás igualando a `contestado` con el valor de `si`

Comment: @BetaM si era el signo se me olvido ponerle una mas, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te sirvio!

Answer (score 1):

```
function imprimirMensaje(res) {
  if (res === "si") return console.log("buena eleccion");
  return console.log("estas seguro?");
}

imprimirMensaje("si");
```

En Javascript es más recomendado colocar ***===*** ya que la comparación de la igualdad  va ser estricta, fuerte o también se le llama identidad. Mientras que un ***==*** se considera una igualdad débil o abstracta.

```
let num = 0;
let str = "0";
 
console.log(num == str); // true
console.log(num === str); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo utilizando correctamente los operadores de comparación "==" y "==="

```
const imprimirMensaje = (respuesta) => respuesta == "si"? console.log('buena elección'): console.log('estas seguro?');
```

Te recomiendo este articulo donde hablan sobre el uso y funcionamiento de estos operadores
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que al hacer condiciones se utilizan la siguiente sintaxis `"=="`  o `"==="` en este caso que es una igualdad o que se idéntico, en tu código veo que tienes solo "=" entonces aqui no estas haciendo una comparación, sino que estás asignando un valor por eso no se ejecuta correctamente tu código